# How to get email from a route in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a feature where I send email link for verification to the user that registers. Now I want to know how to get the email of the user who gets the link , I tried finding it on the route but I can't get it. I wanna get the email of the user that clicks the link from his email so that I can display on the page that "We've sent you a verification code to" like on the example below, is that possible getting the email address through the route? Any idea guys? Thank you.

If user clicks sign in with your account , I want to get the email and then display on the page.

[image: image2]

[image: image1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the user email to the url as a GET parameter like so:

`https://www.myWebsite.com/subroute?email=the_user_email`

Once this is done, you can inject the [ActivatedRouteSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot) injectable to your component. You can then get the params using that `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`.  Your email that is set in the url should then be available in `activaterdRouteSnapshot.params.email`